# Check empty cells and if specific cells in same row has data then assign a value for those empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been wondering if there's a VBA method to fill in empty cells if only some cells in the same row have data. as in the screenshot, i want empty cells in column D to be filled with eg "missing Agent" only if there's data in the same row from columns A,B, and C. Thank you

[image]

I was trying the code below but stopped at trying to separate the data check from applying data in empty cells.

```
Sub Missing_Agent()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheet("Main Sheet").Range("A:D")

    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Item(i).Value = "" And Not IsEmpty(rng.Item(i).Value) Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close,
You need to loop via main column in question.

the `Application.Sum(Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)) <> 0` sums the range `(Ai:Bi)` during the loop. `&` connects the broken string for code with
the variable `i`, which changes during the loop as the row number.
So each loop it changes from `Range("A7:B7")` up until `Range("A1:B1")`.

```
Sub Missing_Agent()
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow =  Worksheet("Main Sheet").Cells( Worksheet("Main Sheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng =  Worksheet("Main Sheet").Range("D1:D" & LastRow)

    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(rng.Item(i).Value) And Application.Sum(Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)) <> 0 Then
        rng.Item(i).Value = "missing Agent"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much , works like a charm, would you mind explaining the  "LastRow " line  and the Application.Sum(Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)) <> "" .

Comment: Just be careful with the `LastRow` , my option may be not the best, as if you will have value (or even values) missing at the end of the column A, `LastRow` will be incorrect.